# How to make JqueryUi Slider vertical-align middle?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, slider

[image: Slider looks like this]

here's my code:

```
<div class="search-option">
    <div id="slider-days" class="search-opt-left"></div>
    <input type="text" id="amount-days" class="search-opt-right input-small"/>
</div>
```

I want to make the slider and input field algin to the middle of the line.

How can i do that ?  Thanks !

My CSS:

```
.search-opt-left {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.search-opt-right {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe try `.search-option * { vertical-align: middle; }`?

Comment: I would just add some padding or margin.

Comment: @Muhd Because FF/IE/Chrome have different padding/margin implementations , so i want to avoid padding/margin stuff....

Comment: Use a CSS reset, you won't have any trouble with margins/padding. It's what I would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be buggy.
What I usually do is make a table. And since table rows start with vertically-centered alignments, it's quite simple.

```
<div class="search-option">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="slider-days" class="search-opt-left"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="amount-days" class="search-opt-right input-small"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

You may then alter your CSS to get rid of the un-needed stuff.